# Como igualar el tamano de las celdas de la tabla de abajo al igual que las celdas de arriba? html css

Tags: html, css

Estoy haciendo dos tablas para poder mostrar los resultados, pero como serian muchos pensé en meterlo en un `scroll` para que se pueda ir deslizando.

Ahora el problema es que los estilos de las dos tablas son iguales, solo que las celdas de la segunda tabla no quedan a la misma distancia que la primera tabla, como pudiera arreglar eso?

[image]

```css
#prueba {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 5px;
}

#prueba tr,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 20%;
  padding: 5px;
}

#prueba td {
  text-align: center;
}

#prueba2 {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 5px;
}

#prueba2 td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: -20%;
  padding: 5px;
}

#container {
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<table id="prueba">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4">
      <input v-model="product" @input="findproduct" placeholder="Search by name"></input>
      <a href="index.php"><button>Back</button></a>
    </td>
    <tr>
      <th>Name:</th>
      <th>Lot:</th>
      <th>Quantity packed</th>
      <th>Quantity of pallets</th>
    </tr>
  </tr>
</table>
<div id="container">
  <table id="prueba2">
    <tr v-for="i in listFinishedproducts">
      <td>{{i.name}}</td>
      <td>{{i.lot}}</td>
      <td>{{i.quantity_packed}}</td>
      <td>{{i.pallet}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

¿Como hago para que las celdas de la segunda tabla sean del mismo tamaño que la primera tabla?

Ademas que el `scroll` se ve muy alejado debido al `width`, ¿como pudiera solucionar eso?

Gracias :)

Comment: Necesita utilizar dos tablas o le sería útil usar solamente una ? Para saber que ejemplo proporcionarle

Comment: ¿No te interesa una solución con `Javascript`? ¿Sabes que podes indicar el ancho a cada columna?

Comment: si, pero no se como implementarlo mediante vuejs o js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías hacer los siguientes cambios:

- Meter en un contenedor ambas tablas y que dicho contenedor sea el que tenga el `scroll`
- La primer tabla la dejas fija (*position: [sticky](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)*) y con ancho de columnas pre-establecidos
- La segunda tabla tiene los mismos anchos de columnas (*copiar [`colgroup`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/colgroup)*)

#### Ejemplo:

```css
#container {
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  position: relative;
}

#container table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
}

#container table th,
#container table td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  word-break: break-word;
}

#container table td {
  text-align: center;
}

#container table:first-child {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <table>
    <colgroup>
      <col>
      <col width="10%" />
      <col width="15%" />
      <col width="20%" />
    </colgroup>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4">
        <input v-model="product" @input="findproduct" placeholder="Search by name" />
        <a href="index.php"><button>Back</button></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Name:</th>
      <th>Lot:</th>
      <th>Quantity packed</th>
      <th>Quantity of pallets</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table>
    <colgroup>
      <col>
      <col width="10%" />
      <col width="15%" />
      <col width="20%" />
    </colgroup>
    <tr v-for="i in listFinishedproducts">
      <td>{{i.name}}</td>
      <td>{{i.lot}}</td>
      <td>{{i.quantity_packed}}</td>
      <td>{{i.pallet}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Algomuylargoquepuedadeformar</td>
      <td>158877789</td>
      <td>1254522215</td>
      <td>151654648989</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Algomuylargoquepuedadeformar</td>
      <td>158877789</td>
      <td>1254522215</td>
      <td>151654648989</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Algomuylargoquepuedadeformar</td>
      <td>158877789123123123</td>
      <td>1254522215123123</td>
      <td>151654648989qweqwe</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Algomuylargoquepuedadeformar</td>
      <td>158877789</td>
      <td>1254522215</td>
      <td>151654648989</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

**PD:** Tenes que borrar los `tr` de la segunda tabla que no tienen las directivas.

Comment: para que son los coolgroup?

Comment: @plus, he actualizado mi respuesta agregando referencias a los elementos utilizados.

Answer (score 1):

El problema en la `tabla2` era que el contenido de los `td` ocupaba mas espacio que el contenido de los `th` de la primera `tabla`, es decir, desbordaba los `td` al no tener un ancho de celdas igual a los `th`, dado que tu primera `tabla` y todas las celdas tenían un `width: 20%;`.

Para este caso usé solo una tabla con un `width` limitado al ancho de los `th`:

```
<div id="container">
    <table id="prueba">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4">
                <input v-model="product" @input="findproduct" placeholder="Search by name"></input>
                <a href="index.php"><button>Back</button></a>
            </td>
            <tr>
                <th>Name:</th>
                <th>Lot:</th> 
                <th>Quantity packed</th>
                <th>Quantity of pallets</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>{{i.name}}</td>
                <td>{{i.lot}}</td>
                <td>{{i.quantity_packed}}</td>
                <td>{{i.pallet}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>...</td>
                <td>...</td>
                <td>...</td>
                <td>...</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>...</td>
                <td>...</td>
                <td>...</td>
                <td>...</td>
            </tr>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>   


#container {
    width: 50%;
    padding: 5px;
    overflow: auto;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

#prueba {
    width: 100%;
    border:1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

tr, th, td{
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

Supongo que habrás usado dos tablas para agregar dinamicamente el contenido de lo que era la `tabla2`, siendo así lo podrás agregar dinamicamente solo con agregar otra fila:

```
<tr>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: #container donde iria? cerrando toda la tabla o solamente encerrando donde hago el ciclo for para imprimir los resultados?

Comment: Opps, olvide agregar el container . En ese caso la tabla va dentro de container

Comment: amigo, lo he hice pero no da resultado xD, lo unico que me falta seria establecer los estilos de la segunda tabla para que quede igual el ancho que la primera, y asi poder hacer scroll

Comment: Que raro, a mi me está dando. Revisa el código nuevamente, lo edité para el formato del contenedor.

Answer (score 1):

Podría usar una única tabla para mostrar los resultados:

```css
#prueba {
border-collapse: collapse;
padding: 5px;
}

#prueba tr, th, td {
border:1px solid black;
width: 20%;
padding: 5px;
}

#prueba td {
text-align: center;
}

#container {
height: 200px;
overflow: auto;
overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<table id="prueba">
    <thead>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="4">
            <input v-model="product" @input="findproduct" placeholder="Search by name"/>
            <a href="index.php"><button>BackBack</button></a>
          </td>
          <tr>
            <th>Name:</th>
            <th>Lot:</th>
            <th>Quantity packed</th>
            <th>Quantity of pallets</th>
          </tr>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr v-for="i in listFinishedproducts">
          <td>{{i.name}}</td>
          <td>{{i.lot}}</td>
          <td>{{i.quantity_packed}}</td>
          <td>{{i.pallet}}</td>
        </tr>
        
        
    </tbody>
    
</table>
```

Y en vez de cargar los resultados en un scroll, en su lugar agregaría un sistema de paginación que mostrase por ejemplo 10 o 20 resultados y evitar la carga innecesaria.

Comment: muy bueno, pero como hago para que al hacer scroll solo baje la parte donde muestra los resultados, es decir que la barra de busqueda y los th se queden estaticos, los unicos que van a a hacer scroll seran los resultados

Comment: Si necesitas scroll imperativamente, la respuesta de @Marcos es la mas acertada